# Unable to connect to public ec2 instance on fresh vpc in unused region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I built a new vpc and subnet, in a region i havent used before. I added a linux ec2 instance and wanted to ssh to it, but the connection times out. I've been trying the same steps in another aws account, owned by the same company, and i get the same results.

I've tried adding my public ip to the security group, instead of all ips, no change.

[image: subnet]
[image: securitygroup]
[image: ec2instance]

The ec2 instance does get a public ip, but i just cant seem to connect to it. I even tried trusty telnet, just to see if the port was open, it is not.

Comment: I dont know how it happened, but i didnt know you needed an internet gateway, even for a single ec2 instance. Once i added an igw and the routing for it.. i was able to connect to my ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new VPC using the "VPC and more" option, and the number of public subnets is not zero, an Internet Gateway will be automatically provisioned as part of the network:

[image: VPC and more console]

If, however, you are manually creating the VPC and the subnet, then you will need to *also* add an Internet Gateway if you want the VPC to have Internet access.

Without an Internet Gateway, the VPC is guaranteed to be unreachable from the Internet. This is very useful when building private networks for internal use (eg development systems).